# What is the \name macro?

Tags: auctex, spelling

Is anyone familiar with the macro `\name{}`? The AucTeX configuration uses it to avoid spell-checking people names, but it does not seem to be defined.  Is it just a mock macro, or it has some real usage somewhere?

Comment: What happens if you write `\show\name` somewhere in your document?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer depends on your preamble. For example, the letter class and many of its derivatives (extletter, akletter, chletter, etc.) define it as a macro to be used like `\title`: you put `\name{You Name}` somewhere in the preamble, and then *Your Name* is used at the appropriate place in the document.

Other classes and packages define it another way.

Comment: Figures that's right - This macro probably comes from the letter document class. However, it is useful for spell-checking, as Charles describes.

Answer (score 4):

When you wrote *The AucTeX configuration uses it to avoid spell-checking people names*, I think you answered your own question.  I've never heard of Auctex recognition of a `\name` macro before: where did you find it?  It is not in the default `ispell-tex-skip-alist` Emacs variable on my setup, so it needs to be especially set up to do that.

In any case, the contents of Latex variables will never be defined by Auctex, since Auctex's job is just as an editor.  To use this macro you will usually have to insert something like `\let\name=\relax`, unless the macro is defined in the right way in one of your class or package files — I suppose there might be one that does that.  And if it has not been so configured, to tell Ispell not to worry about the spelling of people's names you need to add `("\\\\name" ispell-tex-arg-end 1)` to the contents of the `ispell-tex-skip-alist` Emacs alist.

Comment: Thanks, Charles! mpg probably got the right answer, but your solution for spell-checking is useful.